# undefined method `posts_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fe3547d97d8>:0x007fe3546d58f0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to rails and I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `posts_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fe3547d97d8>:0x007fe3546d58f0>
```

I've posted my files below, please keep in mind I'm new to rails so simple explanations would be really appreciated!

Route.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/post' => 'post#index'
  get '/post/new' => 'post#new'
  post 'post' => 'post#create'
end
```

post_controller.rb:

```
class PostController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @post = Post.all
    end

    def new
      @post = Post.new
    end

    def create
      @post = Post.new(post_params)
      if @post.save
        redirect_to '/post'
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end

    private
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:content).permit(:title)
    end
end
```

new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :post %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :title %>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Create" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm guessing `form_for(@post)` expects there to be a method called `posts_path` and one doesn't exist because it hasn't been defined in your routes file. Try replacing:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/post' => 'post#index'
  get '/post/new' => 'post#new'
  post 'post' => 'post#create'
end
```

with

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts, only: [:new, :create, :index]
end
```

Edit: more info:

Read the full page on form helpers at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html, and inparticular, read the section on "2.2 Binding a Form to an Object" and the part that says:

> When dealing with RESTful resources, calls to form_for can get
>   significantly easier if you rely on record identification. In short,
>   you can just pass the model instance and have Rails figure out model
>   name and the rest:
>
> ```
> ## Creating a new article
> # long-style:
> form_for(@article, url: articles_path)
> # same thing, short-style (record identification gets used):
> form_for(@article)
>
> ## Editing an existing article
> # long-style:
> form_for(@article, url: article_path(@article), html: {method: "patch"})
> # short-style:
> form_for(@article)
> ```
>
> Notice how the short-style form_for invocation is conveniently the
>   same, regardless of the record being new or existing. Record
>   identification is smart enough to figure out if the record is new by
>   asking record.new_record?. It also selects the correct path to submit
>   to and the name based on the class of the object.

So, knowingly or not, when you say `form_for(@post)`, you're asking rails to guess the route that your form should be submitted to, based on the name of your `@post` variable. The routes that you had defined didn't match what rails expected them to be.

For more on routing in rails read the entire page at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html, and inparticular pay attention to the section "2 Resource Routing: the Rails Default". Your `form_for(@post)` will assume that you're using "resource routing", which is what I switched to.

As for why your getting a new error? There's somewhere else in your app where you were expecting to use your previous custom defined routes, and now you're using rails "resource routes" so your path names will be different. No route matches [GET] "/post/new" because now the route instead matches No route matches [GET] "/posts/new" (note the plural posts).

Comment: Or pass the name of the route  as in `post 'post' => 'post#create' as: posts`

Comment: Why does it expect a method called posts_path? And how does the code you posted solve that?. Thanks for the answer, and sorry for noob questions =)

Comment: Also, now I'm getting, "No route matches [GET] "/post/new""

Comment: Change it to `/posts/new`. All you need to know about routing is [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: Updated with more info.

Comment: Also take particular note of the section "5 Inspecting and Testing Routes" at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: So changing it over to posts from post worked. But assuming I want the URL to be post/new what do I do? I'm not really sure why it's forcing me to put an "s" on the end. The model is post, the controller is post and the view is post, so why is it expecting posts?

Comment: Just because that's "the rails way". Just do what rails expects while you're learning. Later on, you can go against the grain if you really want.

Answer (score 0):

Here the form is try to find a route to a post_method through a path "posts_path"
So you need to define in your routes.rb file.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
get '/post' => 'post#index'
get '/post/new' => 'post#new'
post '/posts' => 'post#create'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises from the views. Rails cannot recognize the path that will run when the form is submitted. 

You can manually change your form_for tag to point to the appropriate url. 
`<%= form_for @post, :url => "enter_your_path_here" do |f| %>`

This solved my similar problem

Answer (score 0):

you need to rename the post controller and the corresponding files to plural. that's posts not post. and then the route too needs to be resources :posts.

don't forget to change the class name of your post controller to be plural.