# Route to /post/new instead of /posts/new in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is related to a question I asked here: [undefined method `posts_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fe3547d97d8>:0x007fe3546d58f0>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39905556/undefined-method-posts-path-for-class0x007fe3547d97d80x007fe3546d58f0/39905630#39905630)

I was told to switch my controllers, view etc from "post" to "posts" which fixed the issue, however if I did want to use the URL /post/new, how would I do that without receiving the "undefined method `posts_path'" error I was before?

I don't understand why it's looking for "posts_path" when my controller, model and view are all called "post".

Comment: Does your controller only concern itself with one post? Or multiple posts? Does your database only contain one entry? That's why it's looking for posts_path - it's just convention

Comment: @Yule Not sure what you mean by does my controller concern it's with one post. It's implementing the one "post" model. And there is more than one entry in the db, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this before `resources :posts` line/block in routes.rb file,

```
get '/post/new', to: 'posts#new'
```

When you define routes using `resources :posts`, by default the route to the `new` action is `/posts/new`, So to override the same you need to define custom route like I did above. Also, to search the routes, Rails scans the `routes.rb` file from top to bottom, whatever matches first is taken. Therefore, to override the default behaviour, I asked you to define this custom route before the default routes.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, I added "get '/post/new', to: 'posts:new'" and now I'm getting this,

"No route matches [GET] "/post/new"" Why isn't it seeing it?

Comment: hey thanks that works. Now I just need to try and understand why

Comment: I have added an explanation, hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you take a look at [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).
In short:

Because the model `Post` describes only one record, it makes sence to call the model `Post` and not Posts.

With `resources :posts` within your `routes.rb` you define that you will have multiple `Post` objects and you want to expose all CRUD actions with a restfull interface through your controller. Your controller is named `PostsController` that too makes sence, because your controller provides  CRUD actions for all `Post` objects not only one.

Furthor more rails generate some helpers for every defined route:

```
posts_(path|url) returns /posts=> shows multiple posts => plural helper name
new_post_(path|url) returns /posts/new => show one post for edit => singular helper name
edit_post_(path|url)(:id) returns /posts/:id/edit => edit one post => singular helper name
photo_(path|url)(:id) => show one post => singular helper name
```

The route name is always plural because you are always changing the resources. For instance add a new post to the posts resources.

You can also define a singleton resource via `resource :geocoder` in this case you say you only have one of this thing. For singletons helpers and routes are slightly different. But I saw it until now only rarely.